# Vim custom key mapping not working in superuser mode

Tags: key-bindings, unix

I have a custom key mapping `jj` to escape, it works for normal file edit but when I open the file as a superuser the key mapping doesn't work anymore, why?
I use Antergos os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## timtowtdi

As pointed out in the comments to the other answer you could also solve this with editing root's `~/.vimrc` file.  There are other options though.

### symlink

If your personal `~/.vimrc` doesn't have any plugin weirdness or hard-coded directories you could just symlink root's `~/.vimrc` to your personal one.  That way any other settings or future changes would also be available when you are root.

```
# cd /root
# ln -s ~chicks/.vimrc .
```

### `HOME` environment variable

While testing that I also noticed that if my `HOME` environment variable was set to my personal home directory vim picked up the settings from there.  My guess is this would work around the directory and plugin weirdness that I worried about with the symlink.

```
# HOME=/home/chicks
```

I don't have to do this in normal practice because `sudo bash` preserves my home directory and I also get my shell settings too.

Answer (score 6):

When you run vim using `su` or `sudo`, I believe it's running the root user's `.vimrc` (if there is one) instead of yours.

I think the most "correct" way to resolve this is to use `sudoedit` rather than running vim directly as the super user.  This answer should get you going with that: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46699/start-vim-as-my-user-with-root-privileges

Comment: That works, too.  Glad I could help.